# Emscripten simple file processing program

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to port an existing C++ application to WebAssembly, but having a hard time understanding the Emscripten documentation.

The program is expected to have some input from a file and write output to another one.

Here's my attempt to build something minimal: https://github.com/mihasic/hellowasm

Do I need to export the main function? What am I missing?

Comment: What's your target environment? NodeJS or Web browser?

Comment: Web browser, eventually a web worker. Idea is not to make many changes in the existing c++ executable

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--embed-file <path>` to the build command. `<path>` can be a directory path to embed all files within that directory.

Note: If you `--embed-file content` and `content` is a directory containing `filename.txt`, the path you should use in your program is `content/filename.txt`, not just `filename.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, the thing is - file content is dynamically build on the UI.
So far, I can make it work by adding the `-s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['callMain']"`, but it fills like a hack I do not understand